# Can a Kraken choose how far to throw something with the Fling action?

Tags: dnd-5e

[Krakens](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/kraken) have an ability called Fling that lets them throw a grappled creature in a random direction up to 60 feet:

> ***Fling.*** One Large or smaller object held or creature grappled by the kraken is thrown up to 60 feet in a random direction and knocked prone. If a thrown target strikes a solid surface, the target takes 3 (1d6) bludgeoning damage for every 10 feet it was thrown. If the target is thrown at another creature, that creature must succeed on a DC 18 Dexterity saving throw or take the same damage and be knocked prone.

Does this wording mean they can choose to throw the creature between 0 and 60 feet, or is the "up to" wording to cover cases where they are thrown into a nearby wall?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## It's up to the DM.

The rules are not clear on whether the Kraken can choose to throw the grappled creature less than 60 feet.

The fact that the direction is chosen randomly is indication that the Kraken does not have precise control over the *Fling* action. Also, note that it says: "one Large or smaller object held or creature Grappled by the kraken **is thrown** up to 60 feet in a random direction and knocked prone." It doesn't say "the kraken throws".

Compare with the Stone Giant's optional feature from *Storm King's Thunder*:

> **Fling.** The giant tries to throw a Small or Medium creature within 10 feet of it. The target must succeed on a DC 17 Dexterity saving
>   throw or be hurled up to 60 feet horizontally in a direction of the
>   giant’s choice and land prone, taking 1d6 bludgeoning damage for every
>   10 feet it was thrown.

This feature specifically says "the giant tries to throw", and "in a direction of the giant's choice", so the intent is probably that the Stone Giant can choose how far to Fling the target. Note that the Kraken's *Fling* feature does not have this kind of language.

Comment: Where are you getting the capital T from? The Kraken's listing in the MM and SRD does not capitalize the word. Where is the source you copied the text from? The capitalization you use for Grappled and Thrown does not match either the MM or the SRD. I wouldn't care about capitalization, but part of your answer seems to depend on it.

Comment: It looks like you got the capitalized version from Roll 20's compendium. The capitalization is not in the original documents. It appears they capitalized it in order to link to different pages. DND Beyond's Kraken entry also links some terms, but the capitalization is not there.

Comment: The difference in the wording between the creatures seems to say that a Kraken might throw the target straight up.  Would the Kraken be in danger of being knocked prone?